# Tcl regexp example (modify code or alternative solution ?)

Tags: list, foreach, set, tcl

I am trying to match something and if it matches set it to a variable for later use and printing is optional.

```
set pl m4
set ml m14
set match_name ABC_XYZ_${pl}_$ml
set list1 {ABC_XYZ_m0_m5_1_1_1_1 ABC_XYZ_m4_m14_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1 ABC_XYZ_m0_m14_1_1_1_1_1_1}
set found ""

foreach x $list1 {
   if {[regexp $match_name $list1]} {
        set found $x
        puts $found
   }
   break
}
```

The problem with the above code is that, it sets found to 1st element of the list because of match.  This code only works if my match_name is first element of list.

Please correct it or suggest alternative solution. Note ABC_XYZ_ will always remain same. and "pl" will always change as it is dynamic

Note: Reason , I tried break command is to exit the loop when we have the match

I tried something with
`lsearch -regexp $list1 $match_name`  but did not work

I figured out the solution: (NO Need of foreach loop)

```
set pl m4
set ml m14
set match_name ABC_XYZ_${pl}_$ml
set list1 {ABC_XYZ_m0_m5_1_1_1_1 ABC_XYZ_m4_m14_1_1_1_1 ABC_XYZ_m0_m14_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1}
set found ""
set found [lsearch -inline -regexp $list1 $match_name]
puts $found
```

Comment: You have a `break` always at the end of the loop script and all code paths lead to it; it's never ever going to consider the second (or further) items.

Comment: @DonalFellows : You are right , can we do something with lsearch -regexp ?

Comment: @DonalFellows I wanted loop to exit if it finds exact match. Have updated the Question, Please check

Comment: You can't do: `set match_name ABC_XYZ_$pl_$ml`, "_" is not part of the variable name ($pl). The correct form is `set match_name ABC_XYZ_${pl}_$ml`

Comment: @Losko : Yes, it totally forgot about that, good catch. But what is the solution , please advise on that part

Comment: @DonalFellows and Losko : I figured the solution. Thanks for your support